# LinearLayoutParams are causing a casting issue

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I must be missing something really stupid.

I have a LinearLayout in my view:

```
_editTextViews = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.editDesAndLocViews);
```

I am trying to dynamically change the `height` of that view by setting the `LayoutParams`

I have two `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams collapsedParams;
LinearLayout.LayoutParams openParams;
```

that are set in the constructor like so:

```
collapsedParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,0);
openParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

But as soon as i try to apply one of those params to my `LinearLayout`, like so:

```
_editTextViews.setLayoutParams(collapsedParams);
```

I get the following FATAL EXCEPTION:
[image]

At first i thought my project needed to be cleaned as it seems to think i am trying to force a relative layout to use linear layout params, but everything is LinearLayout.  The LinearLayout in question does contain a couple RelativeLayouts.  I don't know if / why that would be the problem.

please help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your `LayoutParams`s' type to either `ViewGroup.LayoutParams` or `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams`.

The LayoutParams you apply have to match the *parent* layout of the view. `LayoutParams` define how a View is layed out in its parent view (layout). Because each layout type takes different parametres for laying out a view (e.g. only LinearLayout has weight, only RelativeLayout can use anchors), they all have their own `LayoutParams`.

Comment: The parent layout?  i tried viewGroup earlier, will try again..  but why the parent layout and not the layout that i am actually changing